# How to convert update/join SQL to Linq To SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I would like to convert this t-sql to linq to sql.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET CustomerName = 'john Doe'
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.TableID = Table2.TableID
WHERE CustomerID = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple way to do it using LINQ-to-SQL:

```
var query = from x in db.Table1
            join y in db.Table2 on x.TableID equals y.TableID
            where x.CustomerID == 4
            select x;

foreach(var result in query) {
    result.CustomerName = "John Doe";
}

db.SubmitChanges();
```

This approach is fine if you're sure that the result set will me small but it performs miserably on large result sets. There are approaches to [batch updates](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx) using LINQ-to-SQL or you could just use [`DataContext.ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386906.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386906.aspx) comes in handly for those few (hopefully) occasions where LINQ to SQL isn't powerful enough.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL doesn't have an "update" statement, unfortunately.  It's possible (but a little complicated) to do with extension methods, `IQueryable`, expression trees, and `DbCommand`s.  One approach is [here](http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx) - there's some source code you can download at the end.

Keep in mind that this might be buggy for more complex queries.  When I use Linq to SQL I generally do all my batch updates/deletes through stored procedures.

Alternatively, if you just want to make the update code easier to write and don't care about performance (i.e. because you know there will be a very small number of rows to update), there is an implementation of an [Update Operator](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/UpdateOperator.ashx) (extension method) that you might be able to use.

Comment: @Aaron: I think it's important to note that the `Update` extension method that you point to is a LINQ-to-Objects extension method; that is, it will perform the update in memory and it's still required that `DataContext.SubmitChanges` be invoked.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, it just replaces the `foreach` loop.  P.S. Thanks for reposting my batch update link. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your SQL Query correctly you want to update the name of the customer with `CustomerId = 4`.

Since you can't issue this SQL directly (as others have already pointed out) you need to fetch the customer with the id 4 from the db (using a `DataContext`), change his name and submit the changes to the databases using `DataContext.SubmitChanges().`